# How can I get the 'facebookScheme' for iOS in an Expo project?

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, expo, facebook-login

Expo documentation on `expo-facebook` says I need to add `facebookScheme` setting to my `app.json` file.
To acquire it, the documentation says for me to access [the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios).
The Facebook documentation says I need to configure a bunch of stuff which requires a Xcode project. For example, configure `Info.plist` file, or install some dependencies which require Cocoapods.. etc.
But Expo does not expose this file to me, it's an Expo project after all!

What do I do here then? Do I need to associate this Expo project to an Xcode project, somehow? Do I need to eject from Expo?

Just to add some context (which might be relevant or not), the main reason I'm asking this is because when I try to login using Facebook on iOS, my app simply crashes (a `SIGABRT` error)! I suspect it is because of this missing `facebookScheme` field.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm dumb.

I thought I had to follow the steps mentioned on FB's documentation, but that was not it. I simply had to access it, go straight to step 4 and copy the values `CFBundleURLSchemes` (which is the `facebookScheme` I was looking for), `FacebookAppID` and `FacebookDisplayName`, then paste then inside `app.json` file.

Remember to be logged in with your FB dev account and select your FB app on step 1 inside FB's documentation mentioned above.

This solved the issue about my app crashing as soon as I clicked the FB button.

Answer (score 2):

For crystal clarity because I'm even dumber than OP, you gotta get whatever the string value is after CFBundleURLSchemes. Literally put the following in your app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "facebookScheme": "fb<probably_your_fb_appId_here>",
    "facebookAppId": "<definitely_your_fb_appId_here>",
    "facebookDisplayName": "<your_app_name_here>",
    "facebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
    "facebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false
  },
  "name": "external_login"
}
```

For a fully functioning app, you're gonna need the other values that come with the app.json too.